# Why are popular languages being asked about less according to SO Trends?

Tags: discussion, trends

On the [Stack Overflow Insights > Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=java%2Cc%2Cc%2B%2B%2Cpython%2Cc%23%2Cvb.net%2Cjavascript%2Cassembly%2Cphp%2Cperl%2Cruby%2Cvb%2Cswift%2Cr%2Cobjective-c) page we can see that the trend for nearly all programming languages have gone down significantly since 2022. Where have these percentages gone? What kind of questions, what programming languages or what technology is growing so much in the trend?

If people stop having questions about programming languages (for whatever reason), what sorts of questions do they ask instead? Are there any investigations how ChatGPT and similar tools have an effect on which sort of questions are asked at SO?

Comment: *"that the trend for nearly all programming languages goes down significantly since 2022."* - No, that's not at all what the trend indicates. It indicates that _those specific tags_ are seeing less use. If you look at, for example, the [tag:typescript], or [tag:rust] language tags, you'll see that they're on the increase, as are other tags like [tag:reactjs] and [tag:next.js].

Comment: Yes, I played around with many tags. And I saw that other languages are growing. But not so much like the big languages loose. Since 2022 also Rust goes down. Typescript and Next.js indeed have a huge increase since 2022. Thanks for this information. This is what I was asking for.

Comment: The plot shows many of the selected languages taking a dive since around 2015 already. Which "new" trend are you asking about?

Comment: The only new trend is that more users like to speculate on Meta about trends, specially when those trends go down ...

Comment: Re *"what sorts of questions do they ask instead*: About [JavaScript libraries](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)? What is the new one this week? [Bun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bun)?

Comment: In addition to some languages becoming less popular, maybe a lot of key questions have already been asked and answered for those languages and people are searching the site to find existing knowledge.

Comment: @ggorlen If I have to judge by the questions asked on meta, I can't really believe that there is more of a tendency to search before asking now :) But who knows, maybe because ChatGPT became a thing that has drawn away a large portion of people who were responsible for flooding the site with easy dupes.

Answer (score 5):

Kind of riffing on this, I was also looking into changes in tags of incoming questions [recently](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/92764?m=56617144#56617144) and wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1778394/2160161/#graph), which looks at influx for questions in the top 50 tags and normalizes by a tag's influx in 2021-07-01 to 2022-07-01 (a period where things were pretty stable overall for the top tags) to see how those tags have changed in influx relative to one another (I was curious about possible connections to the helpfulness of ChatGPT for specific topics). Ignore the data points for the current month in the graph, since the data is still "pending". Strangely, the tags that are relatively unchanged in influx since the release of ChatGPT are platform/OS tags and WordPress (of all things. I don't have any idea why). Also interestingly, meta tags took a huge hit ([array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array), [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)), as well as [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery). If that graph is too noisy for you, [here's one with just the top 10 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1781460/2163917/#graph).

Here's a table for the data from August 2023:

| Tag | Influx Normalized to Average Overall Influx in 2021-07-01 to 2022-07-01 |
| --- | --- |
| wordpress | 1.1577 |
| iphone | 1.0992 |
| .net | 1.0957 |
| windows | 1.0219 |
| spring | 0.8966 |
| typescript | 0.8620 |
| excel | 0.8321 |
| ios | 0.8188 |
| flutter | 0.8183 |
| linux | 0.8174 |
| wpf | 0.7932 |
| asp.net | 0.7893 |
| android | 0.7864 |
| c# | 0.7759 |
| vba | 0.7684 |
| database | 0.7372 |
| reactjs | 0.7268 |
| angular | 0.7213 |
| postgresql | 0.7031 |
| swift | 0.6914 |
| java | 0.6873 |
| css | 0.6817 |
| node.js | 0.6692 |
| mongodb | 0.6614 |
| angularjs | 0.6380 |
| laravel | 0.6326 |
| php | 0.6315 |
| asp.net-mvc | 0.6262 |
| r | 0.6212 |
| xml | 0.6189 |
| sql-server | 0.6109 |
| ajax | 0.6051 |
| python | 0.5971 |
| html | 0.5948 |
| django | 0.5891 |
| ruby-on-rails | 0.5878 |
| objective-c | 0.5671 |
| javascript | 0.5654 |
| c++ | 0.5645 |
| python-3.x | 0.5639 |
| regex | 0.5527 |
| c | 0.5343 |
| ruby | 0.5321 |
| json | 0.5014 |
| sql | 0.4706 |
| mysql | 0.4572 |
| jquery | 0.4416 |
| pandas | 0.3635 |
| string | 0.3588 |
| arrays | 0.3218 |

Comment: "Traffic in general went on a big decline following the release of chatgpt." This shouldn't be directly relevant since Trends deals with percents, so it will always add up to 100%.

Comment: @Laurel While true, it also means that traffic to smaller tags has a larger proportional share of the traffic. Certain niche tags may not be affected as badly, because their core users remain even if the rest of the traffic declines, which means they go up while everything else goes down. The decline disproportionately affects large tags, which is why it matters

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into this a bit as well recently, and it looks like the questions have shifted to more corporate and up-and-coming languages. ChatGPT seems to have had the biggest impact in python/js and other entry level & open source programming languages, which makes sense, given GPT4's relatively high quality answers in this space. Speculatively, since many corporate use cases aren't using tools like ChatGPT for intellectual property reasons, etc, industry languages like Java, C, C++ are less affected.

OSS language drops: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=python%2Cjavascript%2Cpandas%2Clist

Small gains in rust, .net, java: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=rust%2C.net%2Cjava

[image: plot of SO trends for python, javascript, pandas, list]

[image]

One interesting observation from the Java plot (I'm over interpreting here), is that the steady decline in question asking *as a proportion of SO users* appears to stop with the release of ChatGPT. Without any strong argument that Java suddenly became more popular or that a big need for new Java questions emerged on SO, Java popularity may still be dropping. So the "increase" in Java popularity may only be relative, so we are only seeing an artifact of the dropoff in popularity for the entry level/open source languages, which is so disproportionate that it overshadows the gradual decline of Java.